# Understanding use of the signum function after integrating $ \int{\sqrt{1+\sin x}}\;dx $

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Given this integral:
$$\int{\sqrt{1+\sin x}}\;dx $$
We can solve is as follows:
$$\int{\sqrt{\sin^2\frac{x}{2}+\cos^2\frac{x}{2}+2\sin\frac{x}{2}\cos\frac{x}{2}}}\;dx = \int{\sqrt{\left(\sin\frac{x}{2}+\cos\frac{x}{2}\right)^2}}\;dx $$
Therefore giving us:
$$2\left[\sin\frac{x}{2} - \cos\frac{x}{2}\right] + C $$
However, the solution that I was given required that I give proper definitions to the nature of the sign of the solution.

The suggested solution was:
$$ 2\operatorname{sgn}\left(\sin\frac{x}{2}+\cos\frac{x}{2}\right)\;\left(\sin\frac{x}{2}-\cos\frac{x}{2}\right) + C $$
What was surprising was that the function used in $\operatorname{sgn}()$ was different from its preceding factor -which is as demonstrated above, the solution derived.

Now, I understand that since we are dealing with $\frac{1}{2}$ angles, values of $x>0$ will be positive, $x<0$ will be negative, and $x=0$ will be $0$, within the domain $-2\pi<x<2\pi$. I see why there is a need to enunciate the nuance for the solution, but I can't seem to be able to understand how they got that function as the determinant factor.

Can anyone help me with an explanation please?

Comment: Please use ```\``` to write trigonometric functions, so that $sin x$ becomes $\sin x$.

Comment: We have deleted the accepted answer, it turns out it had a mistake. Kindly read the answer carefully before accepting next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify that for $f(x)=\sqrt{1+\sin(x)}$ we have
$$f''(x)=-\frac14f(x).$$
Hence
$$\int f(x)\,dx=-4f'(x)=-2\frac{\cos(x)}{\sqrt{1+\sin(x)}}.$$